# How to obtain internet certificate information located in person document in Address Book?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

The Internet Certificate is in the person document in address book on a Domino Server.  Is there a way to get certificate information (like serial number) without having to use LDAP?  I would like to make an agent to review all the person documents.

Thanks,

Kev

Answer (score 1):

As this is a very bad question (not a minimal effort of research shown, not one line of code) it would not deserve an answer, but the issue draw my interest.

If you check the code behind the button "Examine Internet Certificate(s)" in the person form in domino directory, you will find, that it simply opens a Dialog with the form "(DeleteCertDialog)".

There is a field called "CertificateList" that lists the certificates using the formula:

```
@X509Certificates([Issuer]; UserCertificate)
```

Another field uses the selected value from CertificateList to show the serial- number with this code:

```
X:=@If(CertificateList="";"";@X509Certificates([SerialNumber];UserCertificate;"";CertificateList));
Y:=@Length(X);
@If(Y < 48; X; @Left(X;48) + @NewLine + @Right(X;@Left(X;48)))
```

`@X509Certificates` is completely undocumented, but I checked and it can be used with Evaluate in a LotusScript- Agent. I did NOT check, if this function was translated to JavaScript, that is up to you now.

The parameters for `@X509Certificates` in this form are:

- [IssuedTo]
- [ValidAfter]
- [Expiration]
- [SerialNumber]
- [SubjectPublicKey]
- [KeyLength]

Comment: Torsten,  thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.

Comment: Opps - Just a bit more info.  My goal is to use the serial number to compare to a certificate revocation list(CRL).  I already have code to read any attribute of the 509 certificate via LDAP but wanted to identify another method.  That formula is not available via javascript but between a lotus script agent and a java agent I think I can accomplish this portion.   Thanks Kev